# Searching Through a Directory to see if a File Exists in C

Tags: c, file, search, directory

I'm trying to search for a file in a directory which are both specififed by the user on the command line when executing my program. It should look into the directory specified, and also check in sub-directories within that directory and recursively search for the file.

I have print statements in here trying to analyze the variables being passed around and how they're changing. Within my while loop, it's never reaching the checks for if it's a file or just the else statement saying it wasn't found. The check for if it's a directory is true every time, which is obviously not the case.

Thank you for any help. I'm not very familiar/comfortable with dirent and stat so I've been trying to review and make sure I'm using them correctly in the meantime.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void traverse(char *dir, char *file) {

    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *structure;
    struct stat info;

    printf("Current directory to search through is: %s\n", dir);
    printf("Current file to search for is: %s\n", file);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    // make sure the directory can be opened
    if((directory = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The directory could not be opened. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    chdir(dir); // change to the directory

    while((structure = readdir(directory)) != NULL) { // loop through it
        fprintf(stderr, "before the change it is: %s\n", dir);
        lstat(structure->d_name, &info); // get the name of the next item

        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) { // is it a directory?
            printf("checking if it's a directory\n");
            if(strcmp(".", structure->d_name) == 0 ||
               strcmp("..", structure->d_name) == 0)
                continue; // ignore the . and .. directories
            dir = structure->d_name;
            fprintf(stderr, "after the change it is: %s\n", dir);
            printf("About to recurse...\n");
            printf("\n");
            traverse(structure->d_name, file); // recursively traverse through that directory as well
        }

        else if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode)) { // is it a file?
            printf("checking if it's a file\n");
            if(strcmp(file, structure->d_name) == 0) { // is it what they're searching for?
                printf("The file was found.\n");
            }
        }

        else {
            printf("The file was nout found.\n");
        }
    }
            closedir(directory);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // make sure they entered enough arguments
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You didn't enter enough arguments on the command line!\n");
        return 3;
    }

    traverse(argv[2], argv[1]);

}
```

Comment: What's the return value from your call to `chdir()`?  If that fails, your code won't work.  You also need to check the return value from `lstat()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle good idea. I added checks for both. chdir() doesn't seem to ever error. lstat() doesn't error until about halfway through. It loops through two subdirectories, and then it fails and screws up the rest of the program.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You `chdir` down into directories but never go back up. Everything after the first directory will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a POSIX function for tree walking like this.  It's called *nftw()*.

It provides a callback mechanism and it also detects links caused by badly constructed symbolic link chaining.

So I'd recommend you use that rather than the way you're doing it.

As usual *man nftw* will explain it's operation in detail.  The standard Linux/Unix include file is ftw.h.

Note their was a function called ftw() which is apparently obsolete now.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Medico noted: *You `chdir` down into directories but never go back up.* Thus, just insert

```
    chdir("..");    // change back to upper directory
```

between the end of the `while` loop and the end of the `traverse()` function.